# Middleman and Github pages

Tags: github, middleman, github-pages

I'm trying to create a static site using [Middleman](http://www.middlemanapp.com). The git repo `master` has the source files. The static files are generated in the `build` folder which is in `.gitignore`. I have a branch `gh-pages` for Github pages. How do I setup things such that the `gh-pages` has contents of the `build` folder of `master`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this gem provides an elegant solution:

[middleman-gh-pages](https://github.com/neo/middleman-gh-pages)

Answer (score 6):

I've started using the same technique as [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) [uses](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/), it works great for Middleman.

Basically I use two git repositories, one inside the root folder and one inside the build folder. The root repository pushes to the `develop` branch on the GitHub remote and excludes the `build` directory. The repository inside the `build` directory pushes to the `master` (or `gh-pages`) branch of the same GitHub remote.

To automate the pushing of the new static pages, I use the following Rakefile:

```rb
desc "deploy build directory to github pages"
task :deploy do
  puts "## Deploying branch to Github Pages "
  cp_r ".nojekyll", "build/.nojekyll"
  cd "build" do
    system "git add ."
    system "git add -u"
    puts "\n## Commiting: Site updated at #{Time.now.utc}"
    message = "Site updated at #{Time.now.utc}"
    system "git commit -m \"#{message}\""
    puts "\n## Pushing generated website"
    system "git push origin master"
    puts "\n## Github Pages deploy complete"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another good gem is [middleman-deploy](https://github.com/tvaughan/middleman-deploy). After you have installed it and configured everything, you can simply run

```
$ middleman deploy
```

and your build directory will be pushed to GitHub pages. You can specify which branch you push to in the config. I also have a blog post [here](http://fajitanachos.com/Goodbye-jekyll/) regarding switching from Jekyll to GitHub pages and it talks a little about deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a clean way of doing this. This is a script I've been using:

```
bundle exec middleman build
mv build /tmp/

git checkout gh-pages
git rm -rf .
cp -r /tmp/build/* .
git add .
git commit -m "Update site"

rm -rf /tmp/build

git push
git checkout master
```

Comment: do you know of a cleaner way since then ?